# Print 0 instead of INF or NAN in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable that returns a percentage change based on a mysql query. It works perfectly for any situation where records exist for that user.

However, when there are no records for the user, I have zeroes returning for the root values `($percentages[0]->current, $percentages[0]->prior)`, but my percentage change variable in that situation returns `NAN`, due to division by zero.

I'm using Laravel in this instance and I'm wondering what's the best way to catch any situation with `NAN` or `INF` and return zero instead?

So when I show zeroes for the root variables on the front end, rather than showing `NAN` for the percentage, I just want to show '0'

Here's the variable:

```
$percentageChange = ROUND((($percentages[0]->current - $percentages[0]->prior) / $percentages[0]->prior)*100,0);
```

I'm not familiar with how I should best handle this in laravel but I want to do something like this:

```
if ($percentageChange = NAN,INF) {
    $percentageCHange = 0;
} else {
    $percentageCHange;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`is_nan()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) or [`is_infinite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php) functions

```
if (is_nan($percentageChange) || is_infinite($percentageChange)) {
    $percentageCHange = 0;
} else {
    $percentageCHange;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I saw is_infinite in the documentation for php, but I wanted to make sure first since I know laravel can be quite picky sometimes

Comment: laravel is a php framework so, all the functions from php docs can be used in laravel. At the end, it is all the same